# How to read a txt file containing floating-point numbers separated by spaces using streams to obtain the sum, average, maximum, and minimum?

Tags: java, java-stream

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file.toPath()).parallel()) {
    lines.map(line -> Stream.of(line.split(" ")) //Something something more         
}
```

This is what I have so far and I can't figure out how to take the stream of objects and map it to a double stream so I can retrieve the summary statistics

**Here is the solution to answer this using only map:**

```
lines.map(line -> Stream.of(line.split(" ")))
.reduce((e1, e2) -> Stream.concat(e1, e2)).get()
.mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
.summaryStatistics()
```

**The solution for using flatMap is given in the comments**

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: convert it into doubles and get the summary stats.

Comment: Your `map`'s lambda expression is declaring a variable with a name that's already in context. That won't compile.

Comment: What does a line represent?

Comment: If it's equivalent to a space, you can do `lines.map(line -> line.split(" ")).flatMap(Arrays::stream).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).summaryStatistics()`

Comment: `try(Scanner s = new Scanner(file)) { DoubleSummaryStatistics a = s.tokens().mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).summaryStatistics(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if that what you mean:

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file.toPath()).parallel()) {
    lines.flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split(" ")))
            .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
            .summaryStatistics();
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm just confused why we cannot do the same using only map not flatMap considering they both return a stream.

Comment: the map function returns Stream<Stream<String>> when the flatMap function returns Stream<String>

flat map is like turning the array [[2,5,3,6],[8,4,3],[9,0,1]] to the array [2,5,3,6,8,4,3,9,0,1]

Comment: So applying the same logic of multidementional arrays which can also be achieved using map... Can we somehow use this logic to reduce Stream<Stream<String>>?                                                                                              Stream.of(scores).map(twoD -> Stream.of(twoD)
      .map(oneD -> DoubleStream.of(oneD))
      .reduce((e1, e2) -> DoubleStream.concat(e1, e2)).get())
      .reduce((e1, e2) -> DoubleStream.concat(e1, e2)).get()

Comment: yes (i dont know why there is a character limit)

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to do it because I've been trying for the past 4 hours and it's no bueno for me

Comment: the code i wrote don't work? can you explain exactly what you want (input and output)

Comment: Your code works. I just want to know how to do this using map instead of flatMap. I know that flatMap might be the more simple answer, but I am determined to figure out how to do it using map and reducing the obj to a single string element and parsing it as a double (since there is no parseFloat).

Comment: Here is what I was looking for. It works. Thanks for the help. lines.map(line -> Stream.of(line.split(" ")))
     .reduce((e1, e2) -> Stream.concat(e1, e2)).get()
     .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
     .summaryStatistics()